# Bootstrap Tab creating external link for tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to get bootstrap tab to be accessible via external link... ex: http://example.org/folder#First nothing appears to happen when using the script below. when http://example.org/folder#First is click it should take the user to that tab with it opened.

```
<div id="tabmenu_top" class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs center-block" id="sync">
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="/#First">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="/#Second">Tab 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).on('[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Your html doesn't have the associated content. When you click on the tabs, nothing will happen. You need a separate `div` with a class of `tab-content`, which contains an element for each tab with a matching `id`.

Comment: @Yass i have that part... my question is referring to accessing the tab from an external link

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the required tab when the dom is ready and you don't need the forward slashes in the `href`s. Once that is done you can obtain the hash from the url using `window.location.hash`, which will return `#First` and `#Second` respectively. You can then use the resulting value to select the tab.

**Complete Html:**

```
<div id="tabmenu_top" class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs center-block" id="sync">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#First">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Second">Tab 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="First">
    <h2>Green</h2>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150/00ff00"/>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Second">
    <h2>Red</h2>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

Please see the comments for an explanation

```
 $(function() {
   //Just for demonstration purposes, I've hard-coded the hash value.
   var hash = "#Second"; //You would use window.location.hash here
   if (hash) {
     $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
   }
 });
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/g2bgnyme/)**

Comment: I was unable to full test it since https://fiddle.jshell.net/yassarikhan786/g2bgnyme/show/light/#Second is default to open and https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/g2bgnyme/ too

Comment: You can't test it like that since the fiddle contents are in an iframe. The above will work on your website, if you have one.

Comment: If you want to test it, update the hash value to `#First` and re-run the fiddle.

Comment: I added the code to my page and added a direct url to my browser http://example.org/folder#Contact and nothing happened

Comment: There are no tabs on the url so how would the code work?